# How to parse json (jquery) from google geocoding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-code

I'm trying to get city name using latidute and longitude.

Google geocoding support this option and called "[Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=ru#ReverseGeocoding)".
And as written there in the sample i have to make a get request to this link:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

it returns me array in json, you can try.

how i can parse this json in jquery?

i'm tried to do this like:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
      type: 'get',
      data: {
        'latlng':lat+","+longit,
        'sensor': false
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(result){

        console.log(results)

      },
      error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError){
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
        console.log(thrownError);
      }

  })
```

I get this array, but can not parse. it says:

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**

how do i can fix this?

Comment: besides the typo `jsomp` it looks like it should work.

Comment: @Christoph. Then you can upvote the question saying it...

Comment: @gdoron I know that i can, only the upvoter himself knows if it perhaps was me or not...

Comment: @Christoph. Yep, he got one upvote and it's my vote.... :)

Comment: @gdoron Perhaps, then i didn't want to upvote for another reason... well, who knows >.<

Comment: @gdoron See the comment to the answer, that's why I didn't upvote...

Comment: Denis check the network tab of you console for further information. Perhaps you can spot the error there. Can you provide a link to the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer; you can't: JSONP is not supported here (or at least is not actually documented as being supported), use the [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) class instead.

The [Google Geocoding APIs say:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)

> Looking to use this service in a JavaScript application? Check out the Geocoder class of the Google Maps API v3.

Seems Google only serves up plain JSON, which you can't parse in your own page due to same-origin policy - but which you could consume if you were eg. a php app running on another server that doesn't have that restriction. So if you want to use this on a web page, using their Geocoder class is the way to go - and it will do the work of parsing for you anyhow.

--

When you use dataType="jsonp", jQuery attempts to load the result by creating a SCRIPT element and setting the src attribute to the query string. The browser then ends up getting the returned json, and attempts to parse it as through it were a self-contained javascript file - and that's what's failing.

The problem is that JSON is not valid plain standalone javascript: for example, the returned JSON string:

```
{ "results" : [ { "address_components" : [
```

... fails to parse - and that's what's causing the errors. If it was, on the other hand,

```
var foo = { "results" : [ { "address_components" : [
```

or

```
callback({ "results" : [ { "address_components" : [ ...  } )
```

*then* it would be valid javascript. The latter is what jsonp is actually relying on returning.

Bottom line is that you are getting back valid JSON, but because of the same origin policy, you can't access it directly via XmlHttpRequest; and because it's not JSONP with a function wrapped around it, you can't use it via the SCRIPT backdoor that JSONP relies on to get around the same origin issue. Your only option for using this on a web page is to use the classes that Google provide you - since they are also from the Google site, they *can* access the JSON and parse it successfully - and return the processed results back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `dataType: jsonp,` instead of `dataType: jsomp,`.

Comment: sorry my mistake, in the real code was correct case: "jsonp" and still do not work.

give me a moment, i'll show it in jsfiddle

Comment: maybe someone knows another way to parse that?

Comment: This won't help since the google maps API doesn't support jsonp (which is json with a callback wrapped around it so it can be used as src to a script tag); it returns plain json regardless.

Answer (score 0):

try adding following in ajax setting:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

**edit :**

this is what i saw with firebug:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "285",
               "short_name" : "285",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings",
               "short_name" : "Kings",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },

            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: very interesting !i have checked it with firebug.i saw that response have received.it seems this is a bug in jquery.

Comment: and is that valid json in responce? can you parse that?

Comment: yes it is valid jason as well.but jquery attept to parse that fails with error.

Comment: and i got the same in firebug.  
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38721261/2.PNG  
  
but there are parse error so i can not parse this :(  
  
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the ajax request is not returning anything. Presumably an empty string is not valid JSON?

Edit: And now it is! The first time I attempted the 'fiddle' below, Firebug reported an empty response to the request!

Comment: nope, array is not empty, looks like string is not valid json, but i can not undestand why.  
  
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38721261/1.PNG
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38721261/2.PNG

Comment: Firefox Web Developers toolbar suggests suggests a problem with the JSON - it doesn't like the "results" label...

Comment: The json is fine. The problem is that when using datatype="jsonp", jQuery will load it via a script tag; and json isn't valid standalone javascript; it needs the callback(...) wrapper to be parsable in that context. See my answer for more details.